# Installing Android emulator acceleration for building mobile apps with Meteor on Ubuntu

Tags: android, meteor, kvm, haxm

When I try to build an app with Meteor for Android it asks me to install many dependencies. One of them is the Android emulator acceleration.

But it doesn't seem very clear to me how to do that. It shows a link on GitHub

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux#haxm

But haxm is not mentioned in this tutorial. It says something about KVM, but not how to install it, just how to check if it is enabled.

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you do not have support for your CPU; on an Ubuntu machine, it should be enabled by default.
Keep in mind that this capability is not enabled under a virtual machine (i.e. Amazon EC2, Virtualbox, VMware fusion, etc.).

To test to see whether your CPU can support KVM, you can run `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` in your terminal.

I hope this helps explain why it is not enabled. See the website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation if I cannot be of more help.